# Scorecounter using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, parameters

I'm really new to Javascript and I want to make a scorecounter function for a simple project of mine. I used 2 functions with the same purpose to achieve this but I want to use the same functions for the 2 teams. I'll put the code in here.

```js
var scr1 = document.getElementById('button1');
var scr2 = document.getElementById('button2');
var i = 1;

function buttonClick() {
  document.getElementById('inc', 'inc2').value = i++;
}
```

```html
<div id="scorebox1">
  <button id="button1" onclick="buttonClick()">+1 Team 1 </button>
  <input type="text" id="inc" value="0"> </input>
</div>


<div id="scorebox2">
  <button id="button2" onclick="buttonClick()">+1 Team 2</button>
  <input type="text" id="inc2" value="0"></input>
</div>
```

I'm completely new to functions and parameters and I've searched the terms on google for a long time now but don't really know how to advance. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers and thanks,
J.

Answer (score 4):

Using your existing code, you could pass the identifier of the target into the function from the button

```
onclick="buttonClick('inc')
```

and increase the targets value directly

```
document.getElementById(target).value++;
```

I removed the redundant code in the below example to show only the relevant code.

```js
function buttonClick(target) {
  document.getElementById(target).value++;
}
```

```html
<div id="scorebox1">
  <button id="button1" onclick="buttonClick('inc')">+1 Team 1 </button>
  <input type="text" id="inc" value="0"> </input>
</div>


<div id="scorebox2">
  <button id="button2" onclick="buttonClick('inc2')">+1 Team 2</button>
  <input type="text" id="inc2" value="0"></input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this, passing the html element to the function. If your html is different, you might need something else than `nextElementSibling`.

```js
function buttonClick(element) {
  element.nextElementSibling.value++;
}
```

```html
<div id="scorebox1">
  <button id="button1" onclick="buttonClick(this)">+1 Team 1 </button>
  <input type="text" id="inc" value="0"> </input>
</div>


<div id="scorebox2">
  <button id="button2" onclick="buttonClick(this)">+1 Team 2</button>
  <input type="text" id="inc2" value="0"></input>
</div>
```

Comment: Well thought using the `nextElementSibling` property.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a way for the function to distinguish which team that should get the increased points. We can do this by sending different parameters to the function depending on which button that is clicked.

```js
function buttonClick(team) {
    if (team == 'team1') {
        var input = document.getElementById('inc');
        input.value++;
    }
    if (team == 'team2') {
        var input = document.getElementById('inc2');
        input.value++;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id = "scorebox1">
  <button id="button1" onclick="buttonClick('team1')">+1 Team 1 </button>
  <input type="text" id="inc" value= "0"> </input>
</div>


<div id="scorebox2">
  <button id="button2" onclick="buttonClick('team2')">+1 Team 2</button>
  <input type="text" id="inc2" value="0"></input>
</div>
```

Comment: That works but I think the other answers approaches are a little more efficient.

Comment: Yup, the other answer beat me to it! I'd say this is a bit more pedagogical and simple logic-wise though, and that's what I figured OP needed so I'm keeping this answer up as well!